# Does osmotic pumping continue in plants at sub-zero temperatures?

Tags: ice, osmosis

Every now and again I stop and notice something which I find surprising, and try to work out why or how it happened.  In this case I would like some assurance with the explanation.

We have a bucket with earth in it in the garden which has been left with a twig sticking out of it by about 25cm; possibly bamboo and a bit less than 5mm OD, but I can't be sure.  We have had a few nights of mild frost recently (-2°C), preceded by a week of heavy rain.

There is a triangular icicle surrounding the twig which is 15-25 mm across:

[image: Icicle in bucket]  [image: cross-section]

I am guessing that the bamboo (if it is that) has been preventing the water from freezing and pumping it up to the top of the twig (possibly aided by the expansion of water cooling below 4°C) before releasing it, after which it drained down the stem and gradually froze. Okay so far, but the icicle is centred on the twig, clearly has a triangular cross-section and the osmotic mechanism (if it is that) going on here is remarkable.

Any insights welcome.